# Flatness from constancy of dimension of fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

Let $M$ be a finitely presented module over the ring $R$. Suppose that for all primes $P\subset R$ the $k(P)$ vector space  $M\otimes _Rk(P)$ has a dimension $d(P)$ independent of $P$.
 Can I conclude that $M$ is flat over $R$?
I am asking because I want to better understand the criterion for a family of projective schemes to be flat over some base in terms of invariance of their Hilbert polynomial.
I checked some examples. 
For example let  $M$ be the ideal  of a point $P$  of an affine curve $C$.
Here $d(P)$ is the dimension of the Zariski tangent space of $C$at $P$ so that the proposed criterion for flatness holds.

Comment: In general equi-dimensionality of the fibres is necessary, but *not* sufficient in order to guarantee flatness. However, it is also sufficient when $R$ is regular of dimension $1$, or when $R$ is regular of arbitrary dimension and $M$ is Cohen-Macaulay. See S. Kovacs' answer to the following MO question:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry

Comment: Ah, sorry, I slightly misread the question. You are asking about flatness of a (finitely presented) *module* over the ring $R$, so in geometric terms you want to know about the flatness of a coherent sheaf over an affine scheme (and not about the flatness of a morphism of schemes). Then the correct answer is given by abx in his comment: in the case where the fibres are of constant dimension, flatness occurs whenever $R$ is without nilpotents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes if $R$ is *reduced* (no nilpotent elements). This is (for instance) Lemma 1 p. 51 in Mumford's *Abelian Varieties* (2nd edition). No in general: just take $R=k[\varepsilon ]/(\varepsilon ^2)$, $M=k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot abx: perfect answer! Strangely I can accept your answer but not upvote you. Anyway, in my eyes your **real** reputation  is  huge since long ago!